# What is the purpose or equivalent of the umlaut 'A' in C?

Tags: c, turbo-c

I saw an umlaut 'A' in C for two times. When i open it in Turbo C, i can't find it but when i open it in notepad it shows.Also i saw it in a book (i can't give the source because it is local) and a number 3 that looks like an exponent. Any idea what is this?

edit:
 i found it.
 `gotoxy(12,8);cout<<"Ã"<<"Ä"<<"Ä"<<"´";

 gotoxy(12,9);cout<<"³";

 gotoxy(15,6);cout<<"Å"<<"Ä"<<"Ä"<<"¿";`

Comment: It sounds like you are opening the file with different character sets and seeing incorrect characters in one or both. Also, they have no significance in C, so I would guess they were either inside string literals or part of a comment.

Comment: ... people still use Turbo C ??

Comment: Turbo C uses non-standard symbol tables called "extended ASCII" from the dark DOS days. You aren't actually writing C code but C++. You need to uninstall Turbo C++, burn your source of learning with fire, then download a free, modern C compiler with IDE. For example Codeblocks, which is rather beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 0):

C char arrays do not have a concept of string encodings.  They are just a bunch of bytes in an array ending with `\0`.  You can use `wchar_t` for unicode support, but is this available for [Turbo-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borland_Turbo_C) (circa 1988) ??!.

If you want to use UTF-8, ensure you are working with an editor that can handle these types of characters.  Failing that there are umlaut characters in the ISO-8859-16 single-octet encoding.

If your editor can't handle UTF-8 directly, you could encode them in binary:

```
char umlaut_A[3] = { 0xc3, 0x84, 0x00 };   // Ä
char umlaut_a[3] = { 0xc3, 0xa4, 0x00 };   // ä
// ... etc.
```

One way to find these out is to paste a UTF-8 string into a file, e.g.: `Ä ä ö ü`.
Then use a hex editor to see the numbers in question.